# Macro name escaping without undef

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to know if there is any way to escape macro name and actually show the real name  :

```
#define BUFF_SIZE 500

printf("%d", BUFF_SIZE);
```

Is it possible to not expand `BUFF_SIZE` here without removing the define?

Comment: do you want to do a `printf("BUFF_SIZE");`?

Comment: i don't i'm just asking if its possible to escape a macro name from expansion.

Comment: @mch printf("BUFF_SIZE"); will not expand because the preprocessor don't expand macro inside string literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification):

> Sometimes you may want to convert a macro argument into a string
>   constant. Parameters are not replaced inside string constants, but you
>   can use the ‘#’ preprocessing operator instead. When a macro parameter
>   is used with a leading ‘#’, the preprocessor replaces it with the
>   literal text of the actual argument, converted to a string constant.
>   Unlike normal parameter replacement, the argument is not
>   macro-expanded first. This is called stringification.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 500
#define STR(x) #x

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", STR(BUFF_SIZE));
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you can't print a string with `%d`, use `%s`.